# Converting Picture To Byte Array in java android to store blob in database

Tags: android, image, sqlite, byte, blob

i have a worst problem in some of Devices (getting crash Logs From Fabric Crashlytics) that crash occurs...

i converting the file to byte array and in some of devices this return null but some devices works perfectly not know why this is occuring....

code :

```
private static byte[] getPictureByteOfArray(File file) {
    if (file != null) {
        Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }
    return null;
}
```

crash occurs in that line of code...

> thumb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

Comment: `if(thumb==null) return null;`.